# Operator "||" cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and trying to make text base mastermind, but when i try to check if the users answer is the same as 3 of the numbers i get this error. "Operator "||" cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"

```
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int pos1 = rnd.Next(1, 6);  //generates random numbers
        int pos2 = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        int pos3 = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        int pos4 = rnd.Next(1, 6);

        int answer1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (asnwer1 == pos1)           //checks if answer is the same as pos1
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right");
        }
        else if (answer1 == pos2 || pos3 || pos4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Nope");
```

Comment: You cannot translate `x == i || x == j || x == k` into `x == i || j || k` even if it reads like you can.

Answer (score 5):

All conditions should return `bool` result. `pos3` and `pos4` are `int` - you should compare with `answer1`.

You should rewrite your `else if`:

```
else if (answer1 == pos2 || answer1 == pos3 || answer1 == pos4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (new[] {pos2,pos3,pos4}.Contains(answer1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
else if (answer1 == pos2 || answer1 == pos3 || answer1 == pos4)
```

Ideally your code should be

```
Console.WriteLine(answer1 == pos1 ? "Correct": "Incorrect");
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators such as `||` requires from you to have `bool`ean value on both sides `left || right`. In your example you have first operand of type `bool` and the next ones are `int`egers. Which does not make any sense.

To be able to compare if your answer is equal to these three values you have to use them in a condition-like statement ( `answer == posX` ) where `X` is your position's number.

Example of working code of yours :

```
else if (answer1 == pos2 || answer1 == pos3 || answer1 == pos4 )
// do some logic here ...
```

To extend this into more "generic" way, each operand has to present a `bool`ean value as such :

```
if ( true || false || ... )
```

But since it wouldn't be helpfull to pack raw `bool`ean value into this like such :

```
bool a = answer1 == pos2;
bool b = answer1 == pos3;
if ( a || b ... )
```

You can actually write conditions like the one you've tried :

```
if ( operandL == operandR || operandL != operandR || ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, by

```
 else if (answer1 == pos2 || pos3 || pos4)
```

you meant "answer1 equals pos2, pos3, or pos4".

However, this isn't the correct syntax for that. As the error message states, it's expecting everything inside `||` to be a Boolean expression, and `pos3` and `pos4` definitely are not Boolean.

You could write an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] args)
    {
        foreach (T arg in args)
        {
            if (arg.Equals(item))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] args)
    {
        return args.Contains(item);
    }
}
```

You could then write `answer1.In(pos2, pos3, pos4)`.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!